# How can I create a GPRMC statement with Phonegap GPS?

Tags: android, cordova, gps, nmea

I am developing an Android app with Phonegap. I'm using Phonegap geolocation and get lat and long from it. How I can get a GPRMC statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function for doing so. You can use the [NMEA Sentence Definition](http://damien.dennehy.me/blog/2011/01/10/nmea-sentence-definition/) and other [NMEA references](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm) to encode the positional information you receive from PhoneGap and produce a GPRMC-encoded string.

As you likely discovered, there will be items you cannot reliably change to a GPRMC sentence with high accuracy due to device limitations (you never know if they feature a compass heading, for instance).